# Problema salvar data com Fuso Horário (Time Zone) no SQL Server

Tags: java, sql-server, java-ee, data

Preciso que meu sistema faça o armazenamento de datas (data e hora) com fuso horário (time zone). O sistema precisa suportar múltiplos bancos de dados, por enquanto SQL Server e PostgreSQL.

Com o PostgreSQL a informação de fuso horário é salva perfeitamente, sem nenhum problema, já com o SQL Server a informação de fuso horário sempre é perdida ao persistir.

A aplicação roda em Java 8 com JPA 2.2 então as novas classes do pacote `java.time` deveriam funcionar corretamente, no meu entendimento. Faço uso da classe `java.time.OffsetDateTime` no mapeamento das minhas entidades. Segue exemplo:

```
@Column(name="DT_ACESSO")
private OffsetDateTime dataAcesso;
```

A persistência/Leitura esta sendo feita no padrão do JPA, ou seja, utilizando `EntityManager`.

No SQL Server o campo de data é do tipo `DATETIMEOFFSET` já no PostgreSQL é `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`.

No SQL Server ao persistir a data é convertida sempre para o fuso horário da máquina que está executando, porém a informação do fuso é perdida, ficando sempre o valor "+00" (UTC). Considerando que o teste seja executado na seguinte data **2019-08-01 09:00:00 (-03)** (fuso horário Brasil), seguem exemplos:

Informação gravada no banco de dados ao criar uma data padrão (`OffsetDateTime.now()`) no fuso horário "-03":

```
2019-08-01 09:00:00.0000000 +00:00
```

Informação gravada no banco de dados ao criar data em fuso horário diferente (`OffsetDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("Australia/Sydney"))`) no fuso horário "+10":

```
2019-08-01 09:00:00.0000000 +00:00
```

Como podem ver, ao salvar a data é sempre convertida para o fuso horário local mas a informação do time zone é perdida, ficando sempre o fuso horário em UTC ("+00").

Quando a aplicação faz a leitura dessas datas do banco de dados, considerando horário local ("-03"), é exibido a seguinte data ao imprimir no console: `2019-08-01 T06:00:00.000-03:00`.

Como já dito no PostgreSQL a data é persistida corretamente.

Estou usando o SQL Server 2017 e PostgreSQL 11.

Seguem informações da aplicação:

- Spring Boot 2.1.6.RELEASE.
- driver sql server mssql-jdbc-6.4.0.jre8 (versão padrão do spring boot)
- hibernate 5.3.10.Final (versão padrão do spring boot)
- spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect

Atualizei o driver do sql server para a versão 7.2.2.jre8 porém não resolveu o problema.

Comment: Eu não mexo muito com SQL Server, mas sugiro ver na documentação qual tipo do banco de dados é mais indicado para `OffsetDateTime`. Para usar as classes do `java.time`, o driver tem que ser *compliant* com JDBC >= 4.2, mas ainda sim cada banco de dados trabalha de forma diferente, de acordo com a classe do `java.time` e do tipo escolhido para a coluna (por exemplo, pode ser que a combinação `OffsetDateTime` com `DATETIMEOFFSET` não funcione, e talvez a documentação sugira outro tipo, etc...)

Comment: Segundo esse site da microsoft (https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/connect/jdbc/microsoft-jdbc-driver-for-sql-server-support-matrix?view=sql-server-2017) a versão 6.4 é compatível com JDBC 4.2. Vou pesquisar algo mais com relação ao classe OffsetDateTime. Grato pelo retorno.

Comment: Ser compatível com JDBC 4.2 não é suficiente. Até onde sei, nenhum banco possui suporte total a todas as classes do `java.time` (o postgres, por exemplo, [só suporta algumas](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/8-date-time.html)). Não encontrei uma tabela similar a essa para SQL Server, mas provavelmente, ou ele não suporta `OffsetDateTime`, ou suporta mas tem que usar outro tipo que não `DATETIMEOFFSET` (ou talvez tenha algum outro mecanismo/configuração/gambiarra a ser feito). Desculpe não poder ajudar mais, é que realmente não conheço tão bem o SQL Server...

Comment: @hkotsubo acredito que achei uma forma de contornar o problema. Considerando que as informações de time zone estão sendo perdidas, configurei o hibernate para usar por padrão UTC. Agora o hibernate sempre converte a data para UTC antes de enviar ao banco de dados, "contornando" o problema no SQL Server. Segue configuração: `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.time_zone=UTC`